# NullPointerException in Hibernate for fetch = EAGER

Tags: java, hibernate

I've been trying to solve a problem with a NullPointerException in a Hibernate class when I set the fetch attribute of a @OneToMany field to FetchType.EAGER. I assume I'm doing something wrong but I can't see what, can anyone help?

This is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getLoadedCollectionOwnerOrNull(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.AbstractCollectionEvent.getLoadedOwnerOrNull(AbstractCollectionEvent.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.InitializeCollectionEvent.<init>(InitializeCollectionEvent.java:22)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2002)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toArray(PersistentSet.java:170)
    at testhib.entities.Parent.$$_hibernate_write_children(Parent.java)
    ... 64 more
```

This is the test case I've constructed:

Database

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`parent` (
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_version` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `parent_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `test`.`child` (
  `child_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `child_version` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `child_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_parent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`child_id`),
  KEY `fk_child_1_idx` (`child_parent`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_child_1` FOREIGN KEY (`child_parent`) REFERENCES `parent` (`parent_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `test`.`parent`
(`parent_id`, `parent_name`)
VALUES
(1, 'Homer');

INSERT INTO `test`.`child`
(`child_id`, `child_name`, `child_parent`)
VALUES
(1, 'Bart', 1),
(2, 'Lisa', 1),
(3, 'Maggie', 1);
```

Entities

```
package testhib.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import static javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER;

@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Integer parentId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "parent_version")
    private int parentVersion;

    @Column(name = "parent_name")
    private String parentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = EAGER)
    private Set<Child> children;

    public Integer getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(Integer parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public int getParentVersion() {
        return parentVersion;
    }

    public void setParentVersion(int parentVersion) {
        this.parentVersion = parentVersion;
    }

    public String getParentName() {
        return parentName;
    }

    public void setParentName(String parentName) {
        this.parentName = parentName;
    }

    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}

package testhib.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "child_id")
    private Integer childId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "child_version")
    private int childVersion;

    @Column(name = "child_name")
    private String childName;

    @JoinColumn(name = "child_parent", referencedColumnName = "parent_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    public Integer getChildId() {
        return childId;
    }

    public void setChildId(Integer childId) {
        this.childId = childId;
    }

    public int getChildVersion() {
        return childVersion;
    }

    public void setChildVersion(int childVersion) {
        this.childVersion = childVersion;
    }

    public String getChildName() {
        return childName;
    }

    public void setChildName(String childName) {
        this.childName = childName;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Test

```
package testhib.test;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import testhib.entities.Parent;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder;

public class Tests {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;

    public Tests() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test-hib");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {

        emf.close();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {

        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void canRead() {

        Parent p = em.find(Parent.class, 1);

        Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();

        p.getChildren().stream().forEach((c) -> {

            names.add(c.getChildName());
        });

        assertThat(names, containsInAnyOrder("Bart", "Lisa", "Maggie"));
    }
}
```

peristence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="test-hib" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>testhib.entities.Parent</class>
    <class>testhib.entities.Child</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>uk.co.discoverdorset</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-hib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test-hib</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                            <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                            <enableExtendedEnhancement>false</enableExtendedEnhancement>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The test runs without a hitch if I comment out the "fetch = EAGER" from the Parent entity.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, does anything change if you initialize the children collection in your entity class? `private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();`

Comment: Nope, the same error appears.

Comment: It's a Maven project in Netbeans so as far as I understand Netbeans triggers Maven which runs the unit tests.

Comment: I've commented out the enhancement in pom.xml and the test passes! Do you happen to know the consequences of using unenhanced classes?

Comment: The consequence is that Hibernate has to resort to proxying so the enhancement basically happens at runtime. That has its own set of problems that you may or may not run into; be careful with instanceof comparisons on entity objects for example. But at least this test narrowed it down considerably and should make it easier to research more specifically. I never used build time enhancement myself so I'm basically useless to you at this point.